# Summation of $c\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} e^{tx}x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, characteristic-functions, moment-generating-functions

How can I find the sum of c$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} e^{tx}x$?

c is a constant in this case.

I am trying to find the moment generating function, but I am stuck on this simplification step.

Comment: $\sum_{x=0}^\infty xe^{tx}$ is the derivative of $\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx}$ with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 3):

If $|e^t| <1$ then
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} e^{tx} =\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} {(e^{t})}^{x}= \frac{1}{1-e^t}. \tag 1$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} e^{tx} = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{1-e^t}\right)=?$$

Comment: $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} xe^{tx} = \frac{e^t}{1-e^t}$

Comment: @nrc123: Can you clarify how the derivative of $\frac{1}{1-e^t}$ is $\frac{e^t}{1-e^t}$? Because looking at $\frac{1}{1-e^t}$ as a quotient and applying quotient rule or as $(1-e^t)^{-1}$ and applying chain rule it would seem like the derivative would result in having $(1-e^t)^{-2}$ involved unless you see some cancellation. Can you explain?

Comment: @nrc123 $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x e^{tx}=\frac{e^t}{(1-e^t)^\color{red}{2}}.$$

Comment: Yeah my bad I forgot to put raise the exponent of the denominator.